# Most efficient encoding for mysql varchar column (english only, a-z, 0-9 and -_)?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I have table with 1M+ records. Is utf_general_ci is the most efficient encoding for storing only english characters, numbers and symbols -_  in few columns?

I have index on some of that columns and I'd like to make that columns as optimized as possible.

Comment: Probably `latin1` (= 1 by per character). Check https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-mysql.html

Comment: @joanolo `ASCII` charset is preferrable because of easier collation (no european diacritic symbols)  `BINARY` pseudocharset is also good candidate if no text proceeding planned.

Comment: I gues it is then [The Binary Character Set](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-binary-set.html). I can't find ASCII.

Comment: The `CHARACTER SET` and `COLLATION` are minor issues in any query -- fetching the rows, especially from disk, and parsing them take more time than charset issues.